# Price calculation

Tags: javascript, html

if no of accounts will be below 25 the price amount will be 40,in between 25 to 50 price will be 35 and above 50 price will be 30 how can i modify my code according to this category

my code will be display at the below cases as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  update_amounts();
  $('.qty').change(function() {
    update_amounts();
  });
});

function update_amounts() {
  var sum = 0.0;
  $('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    var qty = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
    var amount = (qty * price)
    sum += amount;
    $(this).find('.amount').text('' + amount);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>NO.OF ACCOUNTS</th>
      <th>DURATION</th>
      <th align="center"><span id="amount" class=" amount">Total</span> </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" class="form-control price"></td>
      <td>
        <select value="" class="form-control qty" name="qty"> 
     <option value="40">1 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>
     <option value="120">3 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>
     <option value="240">6 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option> 
     <option value="480">12 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>  
    </select>
      </td>
      <td align="center"><span id="amount" class="form-control amount">20</span></td><br>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

please help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some updates on your code.
Update your script as:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  update_amounts();
  $('#qty').change(function() {
    update_amounts();
  });
  $('#acc_count').change(function() {
    update_qty();
  });
});

function update_amounts() {
  var sum = 0.0;
  $('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    var qty = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
    var amount = (qty * price)
    sum += amount;
    $(this).find('.amount').text('' + amount);
  });
}

function update_qty() {
  var acc_count = $('#acc_count').val();
  $("#qty").children('option').remove();
  var per_price;
  if (acc_count < 25)
    per_price = 40;
  else if (acc_count < 50)
    per_price = 35;
  else
    per_price = 30;

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var opText = (i + 1) + ' Month(s) - Rs.' + per_price + '/Acc/Mo'
    var value = per_price * (i + 1);
    $('#qty')
      .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", value)
        .text(opText));
  }
  update_amounts();
}
```

and your HTML as:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>NO.OF ACCOUNTS</th>
      <th>DURATION</th>
      <th align="center"><span id="amount" class=" amount">Total</span> </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" class="form-control price" id="acc_count"></td>
      <td>
        <select value="" class="form-control " id="qty">
                <option value="40">1 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>
                <option value="120">3 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>
                <option value="240">6 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option> 
                <option value="480">12 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>  
            </select>
      </td>
      <td align="center"><span id="amount" class="form-control amount">20</span></td><br>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

This will automatically update the select box with price as per your need and also calculates the total price based on the no. of accounts entered

Comment: now script working fine but i want change also price in select box

Comment: check my script. it will update the price in select box also https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/51603/ check this link

Answer (score 2):

Please check the below solution

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  update_amounts();
  $('.qty').change(function() {
    update_amounts();
  });
});

function update_amounts() {
  var sum = 0.0;
  $('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    var qty = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
    var priceVariation = 40;
    if(price >= 25 && price <= 50) {
     priceVariation = 35;
    }
    else if(price > 50) {
    priceVariation = 30;
    }
    var amount = (qty * price * priceVariation);
    sum += amount;
    $(this).find('.amount').text('' + amount);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>NO.OF ACCOUNTS</th>
      <th>DURATION</th>
      <th align="center"><span id="amount" class=" amount">Total</span> </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" class="form-control price"></td>
      <td>
        <select value="" class="form-control qty" name="qty"> 
     <option value="1">1 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>
     <option value="3">3 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>
     <option value="6">6 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option> 
     <option value="12">12 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>  
    </select>
      </td>
      <td align="center"><span id="amount" class="form-control amount">20</span></td><br>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is working fine but i want to Change this amount also according to count  :                           
   <option value="1">1 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>
     <option value="3">3 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>
     <option value="6">6 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option> 
     <option value="12">12 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>

Comment: For this, you need to add value change event on price input and you need to update your qty select list options.

Answer (score 0):

```
var amount = (qty * getPrice(qty));

function getPrice(quantity) {
  let price = 0;
  if (quantity <= 25) {
    price = 40;
  } else if (quantity > 25 && quantity <= 50) {
    price = 35;
  } else {
    price = 30;
  }
  return price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a **map of prices** by *upper bound limit of number of accounts*.

```
var priceMap = {
   25: 40,
   50: 35,
   "def": 30 //if no other upper bound limit applies
}
```

create a method that returns the price after passing the number of acccounts

```
var fnGetPrice = (acc) => { 
  var key = Object.keys( priceMap )
             .sort( (a, b) => a-b )
             .find( s => !isNaN( s ) || +s > acc )  //get first value greater than acc
         || "def"; //or pass the default value
  return priceMap[key];
};
```

Now use this `priceMap` while computing the value

```
var price = $(this).find('.price').html();
var value = ( qty * fnGetPrice( price ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  update_amounts();
  $('.qty').change(function() {
    update_amounts();
  });
});

function update_amounts() {
  var sum = 0.0;
  $('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    var qty = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
    if (price >= 50) {
        qty = qty * .75
    }
    else if (price >= 25) {
        qty = qty * .875
    }
    var amount = (qty * price)
    sum += amount;
    $(this).find('.amount').text('' + amount);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>NO.OF ACCOUNTS</th>
      <th>DURATION</th>
      <th align="center"><span id="amount" class=" amount">Total</span> </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" class="form-control price"></td>
      <td>
        <select value="" class="form-control qty" name="qty"> 
     <option value="40">1 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>
     <option value="120">3 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>
     <option value="240">6 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option> 
     <option value="480">12 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>  
    </select>
      </td>
      <td align="center"><span id="amount" class="form-control amount">20</span></td><br>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change few classes, id according to the responsibility of input/select. Besdie that I added another attribute in options. Have a look if this solution is enough for your need.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $unitPrice = 40;
 $qty = 1;
        update_amounts($unitPrice);
      $('.price').change(function() {
 
        update_amounts($unitPrice);
      });
      $('.qty').on('blur',function(){
 $qty = $(this).val();
 $unitPrice = 40;
 if($qty >= 25 && $qty <= 50){
  $unitPrice = 35;
 }else if($qty > 50){
  $unitPrice = 30;
 }
 update_amounts($unitPrice);
      });
 function update_amounts($unitPrice) {
      var sum = 0.0;
 $('#price > option').each(function(){
  $duration = parseInt($(this).attr('duration'));
  $(this).val($unitPrice * $duration);
  $(this).text($duration + "Month(s) - Rs." + $unitPrice * $duration + "/Acc/Mo");
 });
        var qty = $("#qty").val();
        var price = $("#price").val();
        var amount = (qty * price)
        sum += amount;
        $("#total").text('' + amount);
     }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>NO.OF ACCOUNTS</th>
          <th>DURATION</th>
          <th align="center"><span id="amount" class="amount">Total</span> </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" id="qty" value="1" class="form-control qty"></td>
          <td>
            <select value="" class="form-control price" name="price" id="price"> 
         <option value="40" duration="1">1 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>
         <option value="120" duration="3">3 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>
         <option value="240" duration="6">6 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option> 
         <option value="480" duration="12">12 Month(s) - Rs.40/Acc/Mo</option>  
        </select>
          </td>
          <td align="center"><span id="total" class="form-control amount">20</span></td><br>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```